# NSTimer won't start (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sprite-kit, nstimer

I'm trying to programatically make a timer that counts in seconds and is able to stop when the game ends.

at the top I have this variables defined

```
var timeCount = 0
var timerRunning = true
var timer = NSTimer()
```

and then this function under it

```
func counting() {

    timeCount++
    scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"[z] Arista Light")
    scoreLabelNode.text = String(timeCount)
    scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100
    scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 500
    scoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.03
    scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/4)
    self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)

}
```

I also added this to start the timer in didMoveToView

```
if timerRunning == false {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true
    }

    counting()
```

Comment: You initialize `timerRunning` to `true` but you only create the timer if it's `false`.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a new label node every second. Create one and update its text each time instead of adding a new one over and over.

Comment: alright i fixed that. but now the numbers overlap after every second

Comment: create scoreLabelNode as a class variable and update the content of it instead create a new one

Comment: This bit doesn't make sense: `var timer = NSTimer()`. You should make timer an optional, and only assign a timer to it when appropriate: `var timer:NSTimer?'